# Does QXmlSchema manage includes?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xsd

I made a copy and modified the ["schema validation" Qt example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtxmlpatterns/xmlpatterns-schema.html). I simply added in the resources my own xsd file and an xml file for it. However the line:

```
schema.load(schemaData);
```

fails whenever I try with my own schema. *I know it should work, beacause I can perfrom the validation with a command line tool which uses xerces*. I beleive the problem comes from the includes:

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="whatever.xsd"/>
```

1. xsd and xml files are unchanged
2. File Paths are unchanged, I added the xml file and the "main" xsd to the Qt resource file "qrc".

**Question**: Shall I also add every included schema in the resources ? Is there any particular settings ? Should I load them all with load schema ? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this worked by adding all XSDs as resources. I used the following line:

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="qrc:///xsd/commondefinitions.xsd"/>
```

Where "xsd" is a virtual ressource path, not a physical path. This means the path is pecified the following way:

```
<qresource prefix="/xsd/">
   <file alias="commondefinitions.xsd">../framework/data/xml/commondefinitions.xsd</file>
</qresource>
```

As you can see the physical path is totally different

Comment: I have: 

    xmlns="urn:XXX:YYY" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:XXX:YYY  qrc:///XXX/YYY.xsd"

And yet "no definition for element urn:XXX:YYY available". Well At least it does not crash anymore. What do you mean by "virtual resource path" ?

Comment: Regarding virtual resource path see my updated answer.